# Change number in last row in data seperated with commas in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I have rows of data all separated with commas. How can I replace the last numbers after the last commas with the number 5 in NotePad++?

For example: How do I replace 9, 17 and 124 with 5 in the below data? I have millions of rows though of data and Excel doesn't have enough rows for all the data.

Sample data:

```
2009.10.21,05:31,1.49312,1.49312,1.49306,1.49306,9
2009.10.21,05:32,1.49306,1.49308,1.49303,1.49305,17
2009.10.21,05:33,1.49305,1.4931,1.49305,1.49309,124
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to find the last number and replace it.

Search pattern:

```
[0-9\.]+$
```

Replace with:

```
5
```

The search pattern matches any number (whole number or decimal) at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

These formulas worked for me when I tried them:

Find what:      `[0-9]+\r\n`
Replace with:   `5\r\n`

**Edit**: Be sure to check the last item in the file because it might not have changed if there is no return and newline after it.

Comment: Correct.  Note though, that it may not replace the last record in the file, if that that last record does not have a final return (it probably does, but worth checking)

Comment: Thank you but I cant seem to get it to work. When I go to the search tab, replace. And put in:                                 Find what:[0-9]+\r\n
Replace with: 5\r\n                         I get ReplaceAll: 0 occurance was replaced. What am I doing wrong? Must any particular search mode be ticked?

Comment: Make sure Search Mode is "Regular Expression"